# IOTA API command to request transaction details

Tags: iri-node, iri-legacy-api

I use Curl to familiarize myself with the IOTA API. By using `findTransactions` you can query the transaction hashes of addresses, bundles, tags and approvees.

But which command returns the details of a transaction (confirmation status, trunk transaction, branch transaction, message etc)? There doesn't seem to be a method in the [official API reference](https://docs.iota.org/docs/iri/0.1/references/api-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But which command returns the details of a transaction (confirmation status, trunk transaction, branch transaction, message etc)?

[getTrytes](https://docs.iota.org/docs/iri/0.1/references/api-reference#gettrytes) is the endpoint for getting transaction details from the ledger. It returns raw trytes that can be converted to a transaction object.

You can check out implementation of [asTransactionObject](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.js/tree/next/packages/transaction-converter#module_transaction-converter..asTransactionObject) for trytes to plain transaction object conversion.

**Confirmation statuses are not part of transaction trytes**. They need to be fetched separately using [getInclusionStates](https://docs.iota.org/docs/iri/0.1/references/api-reference#getinclusionstates).